# Superfish menu is overlapped by slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider, superfish

I am using the superfish plugin for jquery here: http://www.oct-alliance.com/test/index.html

it seems like the z-index is not working as any dropdown menu isoverlapped by the silder below

AND

the mouseover dropdown functionality is not working anymore.

you can see the menu is appearing, but being cut off by the elements below it.

I have tried adding a z-index everywhere I can think of but nothing seems to fix this.

Comment: The menu drop down doesn't work at all. Makes troubleshooting your overlap issue impossible.

Comment: Try to create the simplest possible case that demonstrates the issue on jsfiddle.net and post the link with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the z-index of menu div It must be greater then slider div's z-index.